# How to make a view that records the data from a ModelMultipleChoiceField form in database with django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I use a ModelMultipleChoiceField form in my website, because it helps me check the presence of users (employees) at work or not.

But I don't understand how can I recover the data from my form to write them in my model (database).

form.py :

```
class HoursDeclarationForm(forms.Form):
    number_of_hours = forms.FloatField(required=True)
    presense = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
```

views.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from registration.models import UserExtention


def hours_declaration (request):
    form = HoursDeclarationForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        number_of_hours = form.cleaned_data['number_of_hours']
        presence = form.cleaned_data['presence']

        for user in presence :
            #this is the part I can not achieve

    return render (
        request,
        'HoursDeclaration/hours_declaration.html'
        , locals()
        )
```

models.py :

```
class UserExtention (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='utilisateur')
    town = models.CharField (max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='ville')
    address = models.CharField (max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='adresse')
    hours_number = models.IntegerField (null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="nombre d'heure effectuée par le salarié")
```

Thank you for your answer !

Comment: what's the exact problem or error you get? What code have you tried inside `for user in presence`? And what do you want? Create a new `UserExtension` object for each user when the form is submitted? Or just update the total `hours_number` on the `UserExtension` object? Please be more specific.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use a `UserExtention` with a one-to-one field here? At first sight it would make more sense to define an object that has a many-to-one relation to a user.

Comment: @dirkgroten  Hello, and thank you for answering me.  I did not try anything because I simply do not understand how I can recover the data in the form.  Is this a list?  Another type of object?  And I just want to update the total hours_number.    Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes I use a OneToOneField because for each user of the site corresponds a UserExtention object.

Comment: Use a debugger. Set a breakpoint in your view and inspect the variable `presence` or `user` then you'll know what it is. That's how you'll learn about django and progress.

Answer (score 3):

I am very sorry but your question is not clear but you correct the code you can always edit the question

in models.py

```
class UserExtention (models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='utilisateur')
town = models.CharField (max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='ville')
address = models.CharField (max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='adresse')
hours_number = models.IntegerField (null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="nombre d'heure effectuée par le salarié")
```

in form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class HoursDeclarationForm(forms.Form):
    number_of_hours = forms.FloatField(required=True)
    presense = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
```

in views.py

```
def hours_declaration(request):
form = HoursDeclarationForm(request.POST or None)

if form.is_valid():
    presence="a"
    number_of_hours ="3"
    form = HoursDeclarationForm
    if form.is_valid():
        number_of_hours = form.cleaned_data['number_of_hours']
        presence = form.cleaned_data['presence']

    for user in presence:
        print(user)
# this is the part I can not achieve
contex = {
    'a': form,
}

return render(request, "hours_declaration.html",contex)
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('a', views.hours_declaration, name='index'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

]

in hours_declaration.html

```
<html>
<body>
{{a}}
</body>
</html>
```

**you dont need HoursDeclaration dir

and create super user from this commend line
python manage.py createsuperuser
enter user name and email and pass
then go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin and sign in 
and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/a**